# Plot only x-axis minor gridlines in x-y graph in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

In the code snippet below, I get both the y- and x-axis minor gridlines. How do I go about plotting just the x-axis minor gridlines?  Here is my code snippet:

```
plt.subplot(212)
plt.ylim((-500,500))
plt.yticks(np.arange(-500,501,100))
plt.xlim((0,8))
plt.plot(time_ms, freq)
plt.plot(time_ms, y2, color='r', lw=1)
plt.plot(time_ms, y3, color='r', lw=1)
plt.fill_between(time_ms, y2, 500, color='red', alpha=0.3)
plt.fill_between(time_ms, y3, -500, color='red', alpha=0.3)
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='k', linestyle='-')
plt.grid(which='minor', color='k', linestyle=':', alpha=0.5)
plt.title("Response Plot")
plt.xlabel('Time (ms)')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier to do using `matplotlib's` object-orientated approach. The minimal change you could make to your code is add:

```
plt.gca().set_xticks(np.arange(0,8.2,0.2),minor=True)
```

on the line after you set `xlim`. (Obviously you can change the frequency of the minor ticks in that `arange` assignment). In the image below, for simplicity, I commented out the y2 and y3 parts of your code.

[image]

However, a more robust solution would be to change to the object-orientated approach. Its also probably safest to change to using [`ticker`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) and a [`MultipleLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator) to choose the minor tick locations (and the `yticks` too), since if you then pan around the plot, the ticks aren't hardwired and won't break. Also see [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/major_minor_demo1.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

time_ms = np.arange(0,9,0.1)
freq = -500 + 1000.*np.random.rand(time_ms.shape[0])

majorYlocator = ticker.MultipleLocator(100)
majorXlocator = ticker.MultipleLocator(1)
minorXlocator = ticker.MultipleLocator(0.2)

ax = plt.subplot(212)

ax.set_ylim((-500,500))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(majorYlocator)
ax.set_xlim((0,8))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(majorXlocator)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorXlocator)

ax.plot(time_ms, freq)
ax.plot(time_ms, y2, color='r', lw=1)
ax.plot(time_ms, y3, color='r', lw=1)
ax.fill_between(time_ms, y2, 500, color='red', alpha=0.3)
ax.fill_between(time_ms, y3, -500, color='red', alpha=0.3)

ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='k', linestyle='-')
ax.grid(which='minor', color='k', linestyle=':', alpha=0.5)

ax.set_title("Response Plot")
ax.set_xlabel('Time (ms)')
ax.set_ylabel('Voltage (V)')

plt.show()
```